# Q; Flash Mac ONLY FIleReference Stage update BUG

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

This bug ONLY affects the Mac (both Safari and Firefox) and ONLY on the
following conditions-

-ONLY after an image upload using FileReference(up to server then down
into flash)
-only on first browser focus. ie clicking anywhere off the browser and
then giving the browser focus seems to 're-initize the flash runtime
so the stage updates properly.

The net effect is that the stage doesn't seem to render or update
properly, stage coordinates are fugged and any drag and drop
operations don't work!

I've tried both standard drag and drop using mouse coordinates via
stageX, stageY, and then rewriting the entire drag and drop logic
removing all reference to the stage and using simple start and stop
drag methods. Same result each time....

Any chance anyone has come across this or anything similar???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm experiencing the same issue. For some reason, it seems to fix itself when you click away from the browser to remove focus and then click back on.

Right now, as a work around I'm calling a JavaScript function to present a popup alert window, forcing the user to take the focus of the browser.

Here is an example of the function that I'm calling:

```
private function externalAlert():void{ 
ExternalInterface.call("alert", "Alert Message Here"); 
}
```

Comment: yeah, considered doing that myself but not the best solution.
I wish there was some way via javascript to 'focus' and 'unfocus' the browser, the same way you can 'focus the actual embedded flash object.
Or to somehow simulate the effect of opening an closing a popup window programmatically....without actually doing so.

Comment: Its really the first major BUG I've come across in the past couple player versions(9&10)...wish there was a workaround but it seems that there is better QA for the Windows vs Mac versions of the flash runtime.

Comment: yeah, i agree - the bug has been submitted to adobe and I've been keeping an on it to see if it gets fixed.

https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-2674

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a serious issue that has come up recently. Has anyone been able to track it down to just Firefox on Mac OS X (possibly just Snow Leopard)?  I know a few users have mentioned that this bug exists in Safari as well, but I have never seen it anywhere but Firefox.

In addition to the Adobe Bug link already mentioned, I've posted a bug report at the Mozilla Bug Tracker: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=518965